# AJAX Success function never true

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I don't know why my success function isn't working. I mean although it passes the JSON data to the PHP file and changes the password.

```
// this is the id of the form
$("#password_form").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $(".verify-user-loader").addClass("force-display-block");
    password = $("input#password-reset").val();
    url = 'reset-pass.php';

    $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url : url,
        dataType : 'json',
        data : {
                cardnumber: <?php echo '\''.$cardnumber.'\''; ?>,
                act_token: <?php echo '\''.$activationToken.'\''; ?>,
                password: password
        },
        success : function(success){
            alert("success");
        },
        error : function(request, error) {
            console.log(arguments);
            alert(" Can't do because: " + error);
        }

    });

});
```

This file works as expected, it changes the password using the POST data

**reset-pass.php**

```
include_once '/../login/user.class.php';


$activationToken = $_POST['act_token'];
$cardnumber = $_POST['cardnumber'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$user = new User();

$verifyToken = $user->verifyToken( $activationToken, $cardnumber );

if ($verifyToken['status'] === true) {

    $tokenStatus = "inactive";
    $user->signUp( $cardnumber, $password );
    $user->changeTokenStatus( $cardnumber, $tokenStatus );

    $success = true;

    return $success;

}else{
    print_r($verifyToken);
}
```

Comment: What error message is given?

Comment: Did you tested that the value of `$cardnumber` & `$activationToken` coming appropriately?

Comment: change like this `cardnumber: '<?php echo $cardnumber; ?>',`

Comment: Parse error; what makes it really weird is that the script actually works as needed

Comment: So it seems the answer from your server is not (valid) JSON. Fix that first.

Comment: show your server side code.

Comment: @urfusion added the server-side code

Comment: try with `echo $success;` and place `exit();` after that, instead of  `return $success;`

Comment: you need to echo $success; instead of return

Comment: You do not encode your sever's response in JSON. Add `json_encode()` for that.

Comment: ok, thanks that worked, however can u tell me why? Also dont forget to add it as an answer so I can mark it as solved @urfusion

Comment: @AlyHassan : glad to know that. Please check the answer.

Comment: Ajax response should be any browser out put (i.e like html or echo or print_r these are browser output ) . instead of return . @AlyHassan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `echo` instead of `return`, because when you work without function you should need to use `echo`.

So the code will be

```
 echo true; // or you can write  echo $success = true;
 exit(); // exit is use to stop further processing of code.
```

Comment: even if you use function  with  return $success  it will not go as a response to ajax success   @AlyHassan

Answer (score 0):

1 )  you need to `echo $success;` instead of `return $success;`

Ajax response should be any browser out put `(i.e like html or echo or print_r these are browser output )` . instead of `return` .

2) simple add data like this

```
........

data : {
           cardnumber: '<?php echo $cardnumber; ?>',
           act_token: '<?php echo $activationToken; ?>',
           password: password
        },

........
```